# Show only some words from post as preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.1 and model @post. Problem is that I want to show only first paragraph or some words on my first app page like a preview, not all the content. How I can do that?

index:

```
<% @posts.each{|posts| %>
        <h1 class="title"><%= link_to posts.title, posts %></h1>
            <p class="byline" style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">Raksts izveidots: <%= posts.created_at.utc.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></p>
            <div class="entry">
                <p><%= raw posts.content %></p>
            </div>
        <p class="meta"><a href="#" class="more">Read More</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" class="comments">Comments</a> (33)</p>           
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Know the builtin tools](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate).

Comment: Easy and simple! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question but if content is a string

```
posts.content[0,20]
```

will give you the first 20 characters.

Comment: I just presumed the content was clean.  Not a good presumption.

Answer (score 5):

You can always try a combination of [Santize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) and [Excerpt](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-excerpt), both of which are standard ActionView Helpers. I like excerpt when I want more of a random sample of text:

```
sanitize(excerpt(post.content,"Some key text",240))
```

If you know you want to display something like the first paragraph or a part of that paragraph, then I think Truncate would be a good option as @Edward notes or a combo of Sanitize and @ERicM's approach, such as:

```
sanitize(posts.content[0,20]).
```

Answer (score 3):

This also works :)

```
<%= posts.content.split[0..100].join(" ") %>
```

This basically says " print word 0 to 100"

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use the truncate html gem - https://github.com/hgimenez/truncate_html

It gives you the first however many characters, and makes sure all html tags are closed properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 
`<%= posts.content.truncate_words(18) %>` above Rails 4.2
or 
`<%= posts.content[0,18] %>` first 18 characters.